# check if a list exists in a column using sql

Tags: sql, list

I have a database table `TLASM1` which has a field `OBJECTINSTANCE`.

I have an input list

```
('Channel_new .ch.sol_11_37_133_111','Channel_new .sh.sol_09_18_522_3','Channel_new .kh.sol_06_17_222_3')
```

The `OBJECTINSTANCE` column has value as given below
sample 1:

```
 Channel_new .ch.sol_11_37_133_111 PermittedObject KLN 123
```

Function CurrentManager AKSPTM_CODE K130098

sample 2:

```
Channel_new .kh.sol_06_17_222_3 PermittedObject KLN 12
```

CurrentManager AKSPTM_CODE S320

I tried

```
select IDNUMBER from TLASM1 
where OBJECTINSTANCE in ('Channel_new .ch.sol_11_37_133_111',
                         'Channel_new .sh.sol_09_18_522_3',
                         'Channel_new .kh.sol_06_17_222_3');
```

But it did not work.

Also, my table `TLASM1` has 9 million records.

How can we solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use LIKE as shown below

```
select IDNUMBER from TLASM1 
where 
OBJECTINSTANCE like 'Channel_new .ch.sol_11_37_133_111%' or
OBJECTINSTANCE like 'Channel_new .sh.sol_09_18_522_3%' or
OBJECTINSTANCE like 'Channel_new .kh.sol_06_17_222_3%'
```

Comment: But table has 9 million records. Hence it will affect Performance if I use "like" many times.

Comment: Not if there is an index. Note that the % is used at the end of the string